# How to set max request body size in arangodb server?

Tags: arangodb

I'm trying to do an 'arangorestore' operation on my local server. When i start it, i see:

```
ERROR internal error: got error from server: HTTP 413 (Request Entity Too Large)
```

How to configure the server to work properly on 'arangorestore'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArangoDB raises 413 error when a server receives a request body bigger than the max allowed value-512 MB. `arangorestore` has an option `--batch-size` but `arangorestore` should cap the max allowed value automatically. You can explicitly use this option to have lower batch sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing line-based imports on a large file, you can easily split your file into sub-files based on line length with the unix `split` command:

`split -l 1000000 my-huge-import.json import-split`

`split` has other options as well. Then you can loop over and call curl with the output files, anmed `import-splitaa`, `import-splitab` etc.